# Google Play Unpublish app error

Tags: android, google-play

I am trying to completely delete an already published app from Play store. But I get this error message when I click Unpublish app in the red box. How can I remove it completely?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Under the heading "Development Tools", subheading "Services and APIs" it listed my errors.

I found that my app had errors such as the content rating was not set and I had never provided a URL to my app's privacy policy. Why do I have to provide these things if I am unpublishing my app? I have no idea. But it wouldn't let unpublish until I provided this information.